# PHP Captcha System

Tags: php

Okay, so I am trying to make my own captcha system.  I have two pages, the form page, and the form action.  Here is my codes:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Captcha</title>
<center>
<form method="POST" action="captcha.php">
<label>Entered Text:  </label><input type="text" name="captcha">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Captcha!">
</form>
</center>
</head>
</html>
<?php
$firstdigit = rand(1, 9);
$seconddigit = rand(27, 105);
$lastdigit = rand(1050, 9515);
$middle = rand(1000, 20000);
$captcha = "<b><center><font face=\"Arial\">AX-$firstdigit-X-$seconddigit-K3I$middle-AN3Z-$lastdigit</font></center></b>";
echo "$captcha";
?>
```

and then the next:

```
<?php
$captcha2 = $_POST['captcha']; //This is the input field
$submit = $_POST['submit'];  //This is Submit
if ($submit) {
  if ($captcha2) {
    echo "Everything is good."; //Echo'd if everything is good
   } else {
  echo "Please fill in all fields."; //Echo'd if $captcha isn't filled out
   }
 } else {
echo "Direct access not allowed.  Please click submit.";   //Echo'd if  submit is not pressed, and they access this directly.
}
?>
```

How can I take the $captcha variable from the other form and put it onto the captcha.php page?  I figured that $captcha has lots of variables put into one, so how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a session: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Generate a random string when the session is created and store it in `$_SESSION`. Use that value to draw the CAPTCHA and to check it.

Comment: you must use `session_start()` on all scripts that uses $_SESSION variables.